# Maximal left ideals and conjugacy

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring and let $Rr$ be a maximal left ideal of $R$.
Is it true or false that for every invertible $s\in R$ the ideal
$Rs^{-1}rs$ will be a maximal left ideal?

My experiments with the ring $R = M_n(P[x])$  of matrices over polynomials over field  show that this statement is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $r\mapsto s^{-1}rs$ is a ring automorphism of $R$. So it takes left ideals to left ideals and maximal left ideals to maximal left ideals.
So if $Rr$ is a maximal left ideal, so is $s^{-1}Rrs$, but that is the same
as $Rs^{-1}rs$.

Comment: Thank you. The question is rather simple...